# How to set the color of srcCompat in android

Tags: android, android-styles

I want to know how to set the colors of srcCompat in android when I set the image in ImageView.

```
<ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/user_default_avatar"
          app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/stat_sys_speakerphone">
</ImageView>
```

Please let me know how to set the color of vector in layout.xml directly.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you can make it by using an attribute in your ImageView.

You can try this way: copy your vector to drawable folder then open it.

Find anything like this

```
android:fillColor="#333333"
```

and change the color to whatever you want.